# Passing object between siblings (components)

Tags: blazor

Say I have a first component like this:

```
<EditForm Model="@forecasts" OnValidSubmit="@HandleValidSubmit">
    <DataAnnotationsValidator />
    <ValidationSummary />
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>Temp. (C)</th>
                <th>Temp. (F)</th>
                <th>Summary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var forecast in forecasts)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td><NavLink href="@($"/Edit/")">@forecast.Id</NavLink></td>
                    <td>@forecast.Date.ToShortDateString()</td>
                    <td>@forecast.TemperatureC</td>
                    <td>@forecast.TemperatureF</td>
                    <td><InputText @bind-Value="@forecast.Summary"/></td>
                </tr>
            }
                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Save</button>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</EditForm>


@code {
    List<WeatherForecast> forecasts;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        forecasts = await Http.GetJsonAsync<List<WeatherForecast>>("https://localhost:5000/WeatherForecast/");
    }
    private async Task HandleValidSubmit()
    {
        // What should be put there???
    }
}
```

Now, as I have already retrieved the list of forecast objects, I want to pass one of them to any other component, say an edit component like the following:

```
@page "/WeatherForecast/Edit/"
@inject HttpClient Http


@code {
    [Parameter]
    WeatherForecast Forecast { get; set; }


    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        forecast = // **How to pass the forecast object here from the previous one** //
    }
    private async Task HandleValidSubmit()
    {
        await Http.PostJsonAsync($@"https://localhost:5000/WeatherForecast/", Forecast);
    }
}
```

(Indeed, it will be wasteful and useless to get again the object for edition…)

How to achieve this with Blazor? I know how to pass value and so on, but not **how to pass custom object between siblings components**, and for now, did not found how to do this…

Comment: `I want to pass this object to any other component`, will this new component be inside the component you have the object?

Answer (score 0):

What you need is [Routing Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/routing?view=aspnetcore-3.0#route-parameters).

All components have routes, but you can add an optional parameter in the route

```
@page "/parent"
@page "/parent/{something}"
```

And get it like

```
[Parameter]
public string Something { get; set; }
```

And then you can inject `NavigationManager` in the other component and use it to pass the data from one component to another

```
@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager

...

NavigationManager.NavigateTo("parent/" + SOME_OBJECT);
```

Please take a look at [some related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54305596/9119186).

Comment: I cannot see how to pass the selected item from the list (by clicking on one item in the parent component) through the `SOME_OBJECT`to the child component.