# How can I load the same Blazor page hitting same url with different parameters and show the parameter to UI in Blazor?

Tags: c#, url, blazor

I am new to Web/Blazor development, so I can't find how to search the following question.

I am currently working at a Blazor.Server project in .NET 6 and I want to load the same page hitting one of the following urls:

https://localhost:7226/1
https://localhost:7226/2
https://localhost:7226/3

Hitting every time one of the above urls, I want to load the same Index.razor page and at the same time I need to read the parameter (1,2, or 3) to a variable as a parameter and show the same page with a tag  element that shows the Id/parameter number.

How can I implement this functionallity?

Comment: It's called routing.  In addition to @enet's answer see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Comment: you can find your answer under this link:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54303437/redirecting-in-blazor-with-parameter

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Redirecting in blazor with parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54303437/redirecting-in-blazor-with-parameter)