# Redirecting in blazor with parameter object

Tags: c#, redirect, razor, parameters, blazor

I have the answer but I want to receive an object and not with a string or integer how do I?

[Redirecting in blazor with parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54303437/redirecting-in-blazor-with-parameter)

```
[Parameter]
public Produto? produto { get; set; }

_navigationManager.NavigateTo("/login", produto);
```

Comment: You should reconsider your desire to achieve this functionality.  A well-behaved SPA should be able to reconstitute its state from just a URL (for example, a bookmark).  That said, you _could_ come up with a scheme that serializes your object into a series of query string parameters, but ultimately you need to end up with a string (the URL).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add the object as a set of query string parameters, or serialise it to JSON, so that the receiving page can deserialise it.

Comment: I don't need to solve it by getting the id in the traditional way as an integer, so I find the object later.